# Multiple Java dropdowns populating text in multiple divs.

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page which uses a basic script to generate text in a div based on a dropdown selection.

The issue I am having is that I want to have 2 dropdowns which each populate text in their own separate Div. Whenever I try to do this, the first dropdown stops functioning.

Here is my code

```
<HTML>
<head>

</head>
<body>





<script type="text/javascript">
        function showText(){
           var value = document.getElementById('options').value;
           if(value != ""){
             document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = value;
             document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block";
           }
        }
    </script>
        <select id="options" onchange="showText()">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1-1">Option 1-1</option>
            <option value="1-2">Option 1-2</option>
            <option value="1-3">Option 1-3</option>

        </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function showText(){
           var value2 = document.getElementById('options2').value;
           if(value2 != ""){
             document.getElementById('show2').innerHTML = value2;
             document.getElementById('show2').style.display = "block";
           }
        }
    </script>
        <select id="options2" onchange="showText()">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="2-1">Option 2-1</option>
            <option value="2-2">Option 2-2</option>
            <option value="2-3">Option 2-3</option>

        </select>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="show" style="display:none;padding-top: 20px; width: 500px;"></div></td>
    <td><div id="show2" style="display:none;padding-top: 20px; width: 500px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>        



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java or javascript correct ur heading if its wrong !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Your Repeated function showText() in two script tag !

Comment: I am such a bonehead! I cant believe I missed that. Thanks. That was what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

Both your dropdown are calling the same function, change the function name and it will fix your issue.

e.g.

```
function showText() {
....
<select id="options" onchange="showText()">
....
function showText2() {
....
<select id="options2" onchange="showText2()">
....
```